# responsive not working phonegap ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

i crate an application with phonegap and it's contain iframe page
it's working perfectly with android and also in iOS Safari Browser
the responsive not working in application and show desktop version
i activate gap in Content-Security-Policy but also not working
this is my iframe.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src '*' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *">  
    <title>Medica Mall</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.medicamall.com"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is not an issue of cordova nor phonegap, that is an issue of the embedded website.

Comment: @Joerg it's working will in android and also in iOS browser, if the problem from website itself should have the same issue with all mobile device and browser